# Delete Confirmation Need Server Side Scripting

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following code:

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete Report"   OnClientClick="return confirm ('This will delete the report.  Continue?');" OnClick="btnDelete_Click" />


 protected void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   // I have code here but it never fires

 }
```

Once the user clicks on OK how do I get the server side script to fire that actually deletes.

Comment: When the button is clicked do you get to the server? `Page_Load`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't you miss setting event handler for the button? You have several options, one of them might be

```
<asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete Report" OnClientClick="return confirm ('This will delete the report.  Continue?');" OnClick="btnDelete_Click" />
```

see OnClick attribute.

Comment: Thank you. I did put this on the server script but did not fire. Any other idea